# How to display different action bar colors in app

Tags: android

I am very to android,I my app two activity ,i want to show different action bar color in android ,here i am using tool bar ,in my first activity i using one color
but i need second one with different color in android , please any one help me here my style xml file ,

I need first activity in color and second one trasparent  action bar colr

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Comment: create custom action bar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create different styles for you activities.

```
<style name="MainActivityTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base" />

<style name="SecondActivityTheme" parent="SecondActivityTheme.Base" />

 <!-- Base application theme -->
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/someColor</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/somePrimaryColor</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/someAccentColor</item>
</style>

<!-- Second Activity application theme -->
<style name="SecondActivityTheme.Base" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/someColor</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/somePrimaryColor</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/someAccentColor</item>
</style>
```

Then set the themes in your manifest.

```
 <activity
        android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/MainActivityTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

 <activity
        android:name=".activity.SecondActivity"
        android:theme="@style/SecondActivityTheme"/>
```

Alternatively you could include different custom toolbars in each activity, something like this:

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    layout="@layout/toolbar"/>
```

In your first activity and

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    layout="@layout/toolbar_transparent"/>
```

In your second activity where toolbar.xml would be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:theme="@style/AppTheme.Base">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

and toolbar_transparent.xml will be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:contentInsetStart="72dp"
    app:theme="@style/AppTheme.Base">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```